# How to set TextField background same as parent Image background in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I have an `Image` with a `TextField` on top. When the `TextField` receives focus, the image content will be changed. However, the problem here is that `TextField` maintains its own background. How can I fix this?

**Here is my code:**

```
 Image{
        width: 100
        height: 30
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        TextField {
            id: password_text
            height: 20
            width:80
            font.family: "Helvetica"
            placeholderText: "Password"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            clip: true
            horizontalAlignment: TextEdit.Center
            echoMode: TextField.Password
            anchors {
                left : parent.left
                right : parent.right
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TextFieldStyle`. A sample example is as follows

```
TextField {
    style: TextFieldStyle {
        textColor: "black"
        background: Item {
                    opacity: 0
        }
    }
}
```

You can replace the `background` property to your needs. For documentation  see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-textfieldstyle.html).